# Questions regarding the melacha of "borer" - separating / sorting on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, games-toys, borer-separating

Are these two activities considered a violation of "borer" on Shabbat?

- Playing cards where you must separate the cards into the 4 suits (hearts, spades, diamonds, clubs)
- Sorting flatware into separate piles of knives, forks and spoons

Comment: Sounds like two separate questions -- why should these two scenarios be put together?

Comment: Are you keeping the rules of "ביד מיד ואוכל מתוך פוסלת"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 3:78:

> It is forbidden to classify mixed flatware in order to organize each type into the compartment designated for it. Likewise, it's forbidden to take all the pieces of one type and dry them and then put them in their compartment. But it's permissible to put each piece of flatware into its compartment immediately after drying, where he took whatever piece came to hand and dried it alone.

In the footnotes, he clarifies that in the second case, since his intention when taking all the forks is to separate them not for immediate use, it's prohibited; if, however, it's much easier for him to dry them that way then its permissible.

And 16:34:

> One must be careful not to separate, at the end of a game, the various items or cards so as to order them by type, color, or the like, as it's *borer*. But it's permissible to separate them and order them so as to play with them immediately.

Translations are my own, and loose.

Answer (score 0):

The case of flatware is discussed in the [Arukh haShulchan (OC 319:8-9)](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.319.8-9?lang=bi):

> **ח:** ולפי זה יש לשאול שאלה גדולה, דאיך מצאנו ידינו ורגלינו בכמה דברים, כגון שמונחים מעורבים כפות ומזלגות וסכינים, ואנו צריכים כעת לסכינים ובוררים הסכינים מביניהם או הכפות או המזלגות. וכן כשתלוים הרבה בגדים על הכותל ונצרך לשנים ושלשה בגדים, ונוטלין מהכותל כל הבגדים ובוררין הבגדים הצריכים והשאר תולין על הכותל בחזרה. וכן אם היו מונחים הרבה ספרים מעורבין זה על גבי זה וצריך כעת לאיזה ספרים, ובוררן ונוטלן. וכן על השלחן אצל העשירים יש כמה מיני קערות קטנות וגדולות, ולכל מאכל בוררין קערות שונות וכיוצא בזה כמה עניינים, ואם יש ברירה בכל דבר לא מצאנו ידינו ורגלינו בהרבה עניינים.
>
> **ט:** ותשובת דבר זה משני פנים: האחד דבדבר הניכר הרבה לעין הרואה - לא שייך לומר בזה ברירה, 
>   שאין זה ברירה אלא נטילה בעלמא, וכל אלו הדברים שחשבנו הם נראים לעין, כמו בבגדים וכלים וספרים כמובן. ואין לומר הא גם שני מיני פירות נראים לעין, כמו תאנים וענבים, דאינו כן, דמתוך קטנותן וריבויין צריכין לברור זה מזה, מה שאין כן בבגדים וכלים וספרים. והשני: שהרי יתבאר דבשעת האכילה יכול ליטול אוכל מתוך הפסולת ולאכול, שאין זה דרך ברירה ודרך האכילה בכך, וממילא דבכל הדברים שאנו צריכין כעת ללבוש הבגדים ולהשתמש בהכלים וללמוד בהספרים - הוי כשעת אכילה ולא שייך בזה ברירה. (ובוודאי לברור ספרים זה מזה כדי להעמידן על מקומן או בגדים זה מזה כדי לתלותן וכן בכלים אין היתר לטעם זה, אבל לטעם הראשון אין איסור בדבר, ויש לעיין בזה ודו"ק)
>
> **8:** According to this [what was said se'if 7 that "sorting" doesn't only refer to food] one can ask a big question. How do we find "our hands and feet" [idiom: easy to find] in a number of matters.
>
> - Like when spoons, forks and knives are  put away mixed, and we need now some knives so we take the knives from among them. Or the spoons or the forks.
> - Similarly, when somone hangs many clothing on [hooks] on the wall and they need 2 or 3 items of clothing, they will take all the clothes down from the wall and sort out the clothing which are needed and the rest are hung back up on the wall.
> - And similarly, if many books were resting mixed one on the other and now you need some of the books, and you sort them and take them.
> - Or at a rich people's table they have all sorts of small and large plates, and for each food they select different plates.
>
> And like this in many other examples, if there is [a prohibition on Shabbos] of sorting anything, why we don't actually find "our hands and feet" [that it applies] in many cases?
>
> **9:** The answer had two facets:
>
> First, something which is very recognizable to an eye that looks -- the concept of "sorting" cannot apply, only taking. All these things that we considered are visible to the eye, such as clothing, cutlery, and books (as is understood). One cannot say "but aren't 2 kinds of fruit also visible to the eye, like dates and grapes [a textbook case of 'sorting' in the gemara]?" For it is not similar. It is [only] because of their small size and large quantity that one needs to sort one from the other. Unlike clothing, cutlery, and books.
>
> Second, it will be explained that at the time of eating, one can take the "food" from the "chaff"...

The second answer is much like Shemiras Shabbos keHilkhasa, quoted in [msh210's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45114/1570).

But notice that the Arukh haShulchan, because of his first answer, does allow sorting cutlery for later use, because cutlery is too big to really be considered "mixed". This is unlike the Shemiras Shabbos keHilkhasa's ruling.